# How to access variable on client with express-expose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to set a javascript variable on my index.html page when the page is returned by express.js. I am trying to use the express-expose middleware but I am not sure how to get variable set in the static html page that is rendered.

On the server I have:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var user = { name: 'tj' };
    res.expose(user, 'user');
    res.render(config.rootPath + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Index html I have

```
<script>
  var myUser = user;
</script>
```

What I need is myUser to contain the json object user.

Examples I have seen use jade which i am not using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose them like this

```
app.expose('var some = "variable";');
```

https://github.com/visionmedia/express-expose#raw-javascript

The way you're doing it, they're only available to the templating engine (jade). In which case you'll have to do something like this

```
script var some = #{variable}
```

Comment: So if I have a user object (json) that I want in my script, how would I do that in a 'STATIC' html file? What does script var some = #{variable} mean? I get illegal character on the client side.

Comment: @JD. You can't. You can only do stuff with/on variables up until it's redered into 'static' HTML. `#{variable}` is the string interpolation in Jade that outputs the contents of the `variable` *before* rendering HTML. You can't have a "variable" in a "static" HTML. You can only have it in javascript by either of the two ways I showed in the answer. If you're not using Jade (probably) then only the first one applies in your case.